# Volume using Shell Method

Tags: volume

[image]

[image]

 **I know that this integral was done using Shell Method ;however ,I don't understand the highlighted part.Why is 1 subtracted from y?**

Comment: I think it should have been $\int_{\frac12}^1 2\pi y(x-1)dy = \int_{\frac12}^1 2\pi y(\frac1y-1)dy$

Comment: Why do we subtract 1?

Comment: Because the height of each shell is $x-1$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{y}-1$ is the length along the $x$ axis from the curve to the left endpoint of the interval, which is the height of a shell in the range $1/2<y<1$.